# Elasticsearch Date Range Issure

Tags: elasticsearch, range

I am using Elastic Search, In that Date Range Not Working Properly. My Query  Given  Below

```
 {
   "req":{
      "from":0,
      "size":12,
      "query":{
         "bool":{
            "must":[
               {
                  "range":{
                     "lastActiveTime":{
                        "gte":"2019-06-19",
                        "lte":"2019-06-27"
                     }
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate more on  _**Date Range Not Working Properly**_

Answer (score 0):

You should use another date format.
Using 2019/06/27 should do the trick.

In your range you can also determine another format like here:

```
POST /sales/_search?size=0
{
    "aggs": {
        "range": {
            "date_range": {
                "field": "date",
                "format": "MM-yyy",
                "ranges": [
                    { "from": "01-2015",  "to": "03-2015", "key": "quarter_01" },
                    { "from": "03-2015", "to": "06-2015", "key": "quarter_02" }
                ],
                "keyed": true
            }
        }
    }
}
```